# Parser- how to read the file?

Tags: java, dom, xml-parsing

I'm a java-beginner and also programming-beginner and I want to implement a DOM-Parser. My Problem: I don't know, how to read the file into the Parser. I tried to use the IBM-Parser with DOM.

```
package domparser;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import com.ibm.xml.parsers.*;

public class domparser
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    domparser MyParser = new domparser();
    MyParser.parse(args[0]);
}

private void parse(String file)
{
    NonValidatingDOMParser parser = new NonValidatingDOMParser();
    try
    {
       parser.parse(file);
       writeDoc(parser.getDocument().getDocumentElement());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("Fehler: " + e);
    }
}

private void writeDoc(Node node)
{
    short type = node.getNodeType();
    switch (type)
    {
        case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
        {
            String name = "<" + node.getNodeName();
            NamedNodeMap attrs = node.getAttributes();
            if (attrs != null)
            {
                int length = attrs.getLength();
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    Node attr =  attrs.item(i);
                    name += " " + attr.getNodeName();
                    name += "=\"" + attr.getNodeValue() + "\"";
                }
            }
            name += ">";
            System.out.println(name);

            NodeList children = node.getChildNodes();
            if (children != null)
            {
                int length = children.getLength();
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                    writeDoc(children.item(i));
            }
            break;
        }
        case Node.TEXT_NODE:
        {
            System.out.println(node.getNodeValue());
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You have posted a lot of code but you have not specified what problems the code actually causes. Doe sit have errors? -> Post them

Comment: post your XML file also .

Answer (score 1):

```
File xmlFile = new File("xmlFiles/type.xml");  
   DocumentBuilderFactory documentFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory  
     .newInstance();  
   DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentFactory  
     .newDocumentBuilder();  
   Document doc = documentBuilder.parse(xmlFile);  

   doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();  
   NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("type");  

   System.out.println("Root element :"  + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
```

then you should loop and print Depend on your xml file , this is just a Example not exactly for yours .... `DoucmentBuilderFactory` is A simple way to read an XML file in java .